# Resolve authentication get Api call visuals studio excel web-addin

Tags: c#, api, get, basic-authentication

```
private void connect_button(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    string url = String.Format("URL");
    WebRequest requestObject = WebRequest.Create(url);
    requestObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

    requestObject.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse responseObject = null;
    responseObject = (HttpWebResponse)requestObject.GetResponse();

    string resultTest = null;
    using (Stream stream = responseObject.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        resultTest = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    }

}
```

when I debug this

**
System.Net.WebException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
Source=
StackTrace:

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
**

this error message displayed

I create this project on vs Excel VSTO add-in

Thanks

Comment: Where are you seeing the `CORS` error? The above error suggests an authentication error.

Comment: sry my bad, what do think  resolve this?

Comment: Try adding this security protocol before you send your request: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;` @trevor

Comment: you mean after this line `requestObject.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");` ?     sry i,m a newbie..

Comment: No before this.